# Is there a command in emacs similar to `find` in findutils?

Tags: files, grep

In emacs, the command `M-x grep` runs `grep` program.

Is there a command in emacs for running `find` in [findutils](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4isaY-o3SAhXGOhQKHYRbALsQjBAIIjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fsoftware%2Ffindutils%2Fmanual%2Ffind.html&usg=AFQjCNGZXm0XqkPF-djvP--5guSlhO0XmQ), or do similar thing?

Thanks.

Comment: [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile), a fuzzy file finder, can use find, pure elisp, or git-files. [This wiki](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Dired#Find_files_recursively) gives a few more hints.

Answer (score 3):

`find-dired` will run `find` for you.

Comment: +1. And if you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you also have convenience commands `find-name-dired`, `find-grep-dired`, and `find-time-dired`.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you are specifically looking to combine `find` with `grep`, see `rgrep`, `lgrep`, and `grep-find`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many `find` commands that you could use directly or configure to specifically use the external `find` command from `findutils`. Here are some (besides the ones already mentioned by others above) that you can explore via `C-h f` documentation:

```
find-file
find-grep
find-library
find-function
find-variable
find-name-dired
find-dired
grep-find
helm-find
find-grep-dired
ido-find-file
```